# PHP mysql connection in index.html?

Tags: php, html

I have noticed that on my website index.html file that contaisn php code to connect to a mysql database does not run and it's also possible to view the php source. Is this normal? I noticed that when I removed the code and put it in its own php file it was fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, PHP code is only executed in `.php` files.

HTML files contain raw markup and have nothing to do with PHP.
You probably want to create `index.php`.

Comment: "PHP code is only executed in .php files." --- this is just wrong. You can add php handler to literally **any** extension, even to .html or .jpg

Comment: I was under the impression that you can embed php code into html?

Comment: @user973917: it strongly depends on your webserver settings

Comment: @SLaks♦: yep, definitely, +1 now

Comment: @zerkms I think that's why he said "by default"

Comment: @aus: he did that *after*. Read the quote I made, not the answer :-S

Comment: @user973917: you can, but unless the webserver is configured to LOOK for php code in .html files, it's not going to pass the html through php. It'll just serve the html straight up.